# Developing C++ applications, target server has different std lib versions, what are best practices

Tags: c++, toolchain

**Narrow version of the question:** the problem is I'm developing C++ applications, working on a laptop (Fedora 29) with GNU libc 2.28, GCC version 8.3, and my target server (RHEL 6.5)  is GNU libc 2.12, GCC version 4.47. The servers are on different networks then my development environment due to regulatory issues, so to move files between laptop and servers requires using a thumb drive and manually moving them.

If I compile a binary on my laptop and deploy it to the server, I get errors related to the different glibc versions. I'm sure there will be more issues since the OS's are so different, so I just write the code on my laptop, make sure it compiles, and then compile on one of the servers and distribute. That's fine. But, one of the issues is that some `c++11` features are available on my laptop when compiling `c++0x`, but it's not available on the server, so I have to fix the code on the server to make sure it compiles and then pass it back to my laptop so I can update the source code. It's very tedious.

I'd like to get it to the point where either I can just compile binaries on my laptop and pass the binaries to the servers or, failing that, just set up a second tool chain on my laptop that mirrors what is on the server. I grabbed RPM files for glibc, gcc, stdlibc++, gcc-c++, and a few others libraries to match what is on the server.

**Broader version:** What are best practices for developing for target systems in C++ with different std lib versions? Is it simply installing a VM of the target system and doing all my work there? Or can I get it close enough by installing the same library versions side by side? It seems like most people are assumed to know this stuff already and I may just have a huge gap in my knowledge, is there any condensed reference material that I could be pointed to if that's the case?

Comment: Docker, perhaps?

Comment: btw the narrow version is already rather broad ;)

Comment: Unless you can make a fully self-contained binary (e.g. all static libraries linked in, no dynamic dependencies) then this is probably not possible. As Severin points out, this is why [Docker](https://www.docker.com) was made.

Comment: Having a VM / local test system Id say is a must. While you can of course develop some things locally, ultimately deploying to a secure production system directly from your local desktop is probably not the best idea, sooner or later something won't work and then seems you have no easy way to debug?

Comment: @user463035818 While it is true that portable C++ should *compile* on other systems, expecting compiled binaries to work on another distribution/platform at the very least introduces a lot more to consider, allthough is perfectly possible. Transferring the source and compiling on the server is of course an option, although personally I have never liked compiling on production servers directly.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the target system Cross-compilation could be a viable solution as well.

Comment: @FireLancer I missed the point that OP wants to compile on one system and run on another one. Crosscompiling is slightly different story than writing portable code. Deleted the comment

Comment: I don't think Docker is an option, the system is quite locked down and the admins probably don't want to deal with having another process running just to run my binaries.

Comment: @VTT I'd like to read more about cross-compiling, almost everything I see is about compiling to embedded though. Is cross-compiling in the manner I'm outlining a reasonable use case? If so, do you know of any resources on how to set this up? I'd imagine compiling between Fedora and RHEL isn't that uncommon

Comment: Docker seems the best choice here - to clarify, on your laptop, not on target server. Cross-compiling between Linux platforms different only in glibc and compiler version might be painful, because very few people would do this.

Comment: @SergeyA okay, so the idea would be create a Docker that matches the server for testing and compiling, and then the binaries should work on the server?

Comment: Yep, this is the idea.

Comment: @SergeyA sounds simple enough. What a world we live in! Can accept that as an answer if you want to write it up

Comment: The thing with cross-compilation is that settings up a cross-compilation toolchain when you can just fetch a ready VM image that exactly matches target could be a bit wasteful. Also it won't allow to test build artifacts. Cross compilation sometimes is the only option when dialing with embedded systems. I may also be helpful when you have a dedicated build / packaging server. Even though docker seems to be most recommended, it may also turn out to be not suitable for some situations, mostly when software requires particular kernel / low level feature while docker always uses host OS kernel.

Comment: @VTT yeah it does look to be a huge pain setting up cross compilation. I think I'll try both the VM and Docker and play around with them, thanks for your advice

Comment: @MartinBoros `so the idea would be create a Docker that matches the server for testing and compiling, and then the binaries should work on the server?` Yes, that  is how we use it. Write code on laptop, docker matching server, shell to docker, build in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments, there are 3 main options.

Cross-compile; this is the most difficult to set up and error-prone, which is why it is largely relegated to embedded applications.

Docker(containers); easiest method, just create a container that matches your deployment server, compile the code in the container, and binaries can then be deployed to server. However, Docker uses the host machines kernel in the container, so there is the chance that incompatible binaries will be created.

Virtual Machine; a little more work to set up compared to Docker, but because it has it's own kernel there's less of a chance for creating incompatible binaries. With vagrant, it's actually about as easy to set up as Docker but I did run into a few places where the VM was failing with no real error messages; but for most people it "just works".

I ended up going with Docker, it's working fine and was very easy to set up.